# Forge Viewer: How to Link Spaces to 2D Sheets

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a Revit file with spaces information in a 2D view. However, when I access that view through Forge, the spaces information is gone. Looking deeper, I find the spaces are in the 3D "New Construction" view (generated by BIM 360). How can I use the spaces information with the 2D view? I would like to be able to select a space and go to its corresponding location on the 2D view.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from 3D to 2D or vice versa is demonstrated in this example:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/NestedViewerExtension/README.md